# Springboot oauth2 how to disable JSESSIONID cookie

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`, it works great for the "Authorization Code Flow". However, it seems after the callback/redirect, spring will use the JSESSIONID in the cookie to manage the authenticated user. I have trouble finding how to disable the behavior and I'd like to set the access_token directly in the cookie.